# When reading string from a socket, the first character is not printed

Tags: c, linux, sockets, character-encoding

The input from the user is insert to 'buffer'.

### **Code**

```
while(1)
 {
     puts("\n#listening");

     puts("#Enter your message:");
     fgets(buffer,255,stdin);
     int n = write(s,buffer,strlen(buffer));// char buffer[512];
     printf("\n>> Writing to server: %d bytes",n);

     int r = read(s,buffer,strlen(buffer));
     if(r > 0)
     {
             printf("\n>> Reading from server: %d :%s",r,buffer);
     }
 }
```

### Output

```
#listening
#Enter your message:
Hello World!

>> Writing to server: 13 bytes
>> Reading from server: 12 :ello World!
```

As you can see the first 'H' is not printed.

Comment: int r = read(s,buffer,strlen(buffer)+1); ?  strlen("Hello World!") = 12

Comment: `int r = read(s,buffer,strlen(buffer));` is foolish, because it uses the size of the string already in buffer, not the size of the string being received (usually they aren't the same):

Answer (score 1):

There are problems with this code, but none of them would drop the first character in a received message.

It is the "server" program on the far end of the socket which is responsible for losing the character.

Answer (score -1):

1. Try to put the "\n" at the **end** of `printf()` statements, it's cleaner and will help you in debugging.
2. You are also sending the newline, that's why there are 13 bytes at `write()`; that might mess up with the way you're printing on the console.

All in all, I think you are getting the "H" back but you're not printing it right.

Comment: Aren't printing it right how? There is no error in the code that prints the data.